# Keeping session alive

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm programming a company website which has an admin page for controlling data. As I went through forums and user guides, I learned that codeigniter's session stays 5 mins and gets destroyed once it's created. I do not want this to happen when an admin is manipulating data :(

Should I keep writing 'session_start()' in the controllers belongs to admin pages to keep the session fresh and alive? :(

Comment: [Does this help?](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/219197/#1011046)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but not quite was related to my issue :)

Comment: I apologize. I misunderstood. That's why I didn't post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using autoload and never knew it calls session_start() for me :/

Comment: can someone explain this answer a bit more?

Comment: urrrgggggg..... Im sorry but I can't recall how I fixed it... are you having the same issue?

Comment: I am yet to work on it. I was looking for better options ;) anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just change your session config?

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'yoursite';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;   <- make this longer
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;   <- make this longer
```